# How to list all registered MTurk notification settings in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, mechanicalturk, mturk

### Boto3 `update_notification_settings`

Is there a way to list all notifications registered via [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.update_notification_settings)? I.e. notifications registered as follows:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("mturk")
client.update_notification_settings(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems no way to describe or list notification setting from HIT or HITType.

We can only use `update_notification_settings()` to creates, updates, disables or re-enables. When updated, the older notification is just replaced. (ref [doc-boto3-v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.update_notification_settings))